# Why won't Maple evaluate this integral?

Tags: int, integration, limits, maple

```
restart;
assume(alph>0);
assume(alph,real);
f_exp:=exp(-alph*r^2);
ff_deriv:=simplify(r^2*f_exp^2);
ff:=simplify(int(ff_deriv,r=0..infinity));
```

It seems to understand what I'm trying to integrate but when I try and find ff it comes up with an awful expression full of erf functions and with a `lim r--> infinity` at the front. However on wolfram alpha I get the answer that I want:`sqrt(pi/2)/(8*alpha^(3/2))`.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second assume call wipes out the first assumption.  As the property > 0 implies real, just drop the second assumption.

```
assume(alph>0);
f_exp:=exp(-alph*r^2);
ff_deriv:=simplify(r^2*f_exp^2);
ff:=simplify(int(ff_deriv,r=0..infinity));
```

Will give you the answer you want: (1/16)*sqrt(2)*sqrt(Pi)/alph^(3/2)

You could also use additionally(alph,) if you had needed another property.